# Adding stylesheets using wp_enqueue_style only affects admin panel

Tags: css, wordpress, stylesheet

I'm building a custom Wordpress-theme and have started from scratch, with a bare minimum of theme files. I've already added a custom stylesheet to the admin panel using `admin_enqueue_scripts` and are trying to add one to the front end of the page using `wp_enqueue_scripts`, so far only consisting of the index.php. Using the below code returns no changes, and viewing the source code reveals that no stylesheet have been added.

```
function diverse_stilsett() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ansattpanel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ansattpanel.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'diverse_stilsett' );
```

But if i remove the function and enqueue the style directly it for some reason affects the admin panel, not index.php - which is what I'm trying to do.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'ansattpanel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ansattpanel.css' );
```

Anyone able to spot what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you calling `wp_head()` in the theme's header or index file?

Comment: Spot on, I was not. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I posted it as an answer, if you wouldn't mind accepting it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scripts and styles to be loaded correctly on the front end of a WordPress theme using `wp_enqueue_scripts`, the `wp_head()` function must be called in the theme's header.php file or index.php file

It's also advisable to add `wp_footer()` to the theme's footer.php file